# Scrolls in Mage the Awakening that perhaps even Sleepers may use?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

**Does Mage: The Awakening have official rules for scrolls** (containing spells, of course, in the "old school" sense. :)) that perhaps even Sleepers can use? If so, please provide the book title and page number reference. If not, does anyone have a quick but functional house rule for such magic items?

Comment: They call them "spells" in *Awakening*, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's a scroll? It's a piece of paper with words on it that, when read, cause a spell to be cast. Sounds like an **imbued item** with a contingent trigger to me. The *Mage: The Awakening* core book describes them on page 84, with a reference to the "Imbue Item" rote (Prime •••) on page 225.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that such scrolls will still be subject to disbelief and paraox due to the presence of sleepers, so try and keep the effect subtle when imbuing.