# Do Mortals have a means of casting magic?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, magic, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

So far in the World of Darkness, most forms of magic seem to be directly connected with being a supernatural entity (or finding a way to have dealings with one). Are there any rules that allow for Mortal spellcasting? Such as allowing them to use a ritual they found in a book. Maybe that ritual is voodoo, maybe it's ancient Latin, or Summarian. This effect wouldn't necessarily allow the to *create* their own spells, or rituals, simply attempt to cast them. Does anything like that exist?

Comment: I think this is quiet different between nwod and nwod-gmc.
In nWoD Casting magic as a mortal means getting a minor supernatural template.(in some cases, gettign a merit template, like the cultist stuff)
In GMC those capacities are now supernatural merits, that are open only to mortals without templates
.
Though in both there are certain magics that can be done by mortals, like exorcisms (iirc).

I thus suggest you split this into two questions, (Infact you could even go for three and have oWoD), and link them all together.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to make that kind of thing happen. If you're looking for ways for mortals to be spellcasters that don't have a major template, that's in *WoD: Second Sight*. If you'd like there to be rituals that can be found in books, you might do well with magical items from *WoD: Reliquary*. Plus, there's a pretty good answer to [this question about sleepers using scrolls and other imbued items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11784/scrolls-in-mage-the-awakening-that-perhaps-even-sleepers-may-use).

Answer (score 2):

They can use "Ritual Magic" p140 of Witch Finders

> Magic is usually the result of the will of a single practitioner triumphing over the rules of reality to create spell effects.
>   For individuals without the knowledge or ability to manage
>   these effects alone there exists the option of cooperative magic, in the form of rituals. Ritual magic is a far slower and more
>   tedious form of the art than that practiced by most witches,
>   but it does work. In ritual magic, the will of the group (covens
>   or cabals) allows the witches to cast spells that they wouldn’t
>   be capable of individually. The practice of ritual magic gave
>   birth to such concepts as spell components, day-long chanting and specific numbers of witches required to cast a spell.
>
> It is important to note that anyone with a solid understanding of the occult (Occult Skill at two dots or more) can
>   contribute to a ritual; possession of the Gnosis Merit isn’t required.